# How to get Count of objects by aggregate within Queryset class

Tags: python, django

i want to get object that is Maximum length/count of ManyToMany Field

```
class Member(models.Model):
    pass

class Chatroom(models.Model):
    ...
    members = models.ManyToMany(Member)
    ...

chatRoom = Chatroom.objects.aggregate(Max('members'))
### {'members__max':15}
```

this code does not  return an object like:class <QuerySet [object]>
but i want to take an object to do something so i did do this

```
room = ChatRoom.objects.aggregate(max_value=Max('members')).get(members__count=max_value)
```

its got an Error : it says there is no __count look up..
could you help me please...

Comment: Do you simply want the `ChatRoom` with the most members? Note that `Max('members')` will not do what you assume it does, it will only give the maximum _id_ of the `Member` table.

Answer (score 1):

Likely the easiest way to obtain the `Chatroom` with the largest number of members is with:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Chatroom.objects.annotate(
    nmembers=Count('members')
).order_by('-nmembers').first()
```

Since [django-3.2](/questions/tagged/django-3.2), you can work with [**`.alias(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#alias) to prevent calculating the number of members twice:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Chatroom.objects.alias(
    nmembers=Count('members')
).order_by('-nmembers').first()
```